# How do I free() after malloc() when the result of malloc() is returned by the function?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following instance method (adapted from **Listing 3-6** of the Event Handling section in the iPhone Application Programming Guide):

```
- (CGPoint)originOfTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint *touchOriginPoint = (CGPoint *)CFDictionaryGetValue(touchOriginPoints, touch);
    if (touchOriginPoint == NULL)
    {
        touchOriginPoint = (CGPoint *)malloc(sizeof(CGPoint)); // leaks
        CFDictionarySetValue(touchOriginPoints, touch, touchOriginPoint);
        *touchOriginPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    }
    return *touchOriginPoint;
}
```

Every once in a while my app leaks 16 Bytes as a result of the call to `malloc()`. I'm not sure how to return `touchOriginPoint` while `free()`ing it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not care a *minor* performance loss, use an `NSMutableDictionary` and store the point as an `NSValue`:

```
NSValue* touchOriginPointValue = [touchOriginPoints objectForKey:touch];
if (touchOriginPointValue == nil) {
   touchOriginPointValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[touch locationInView:touch.view]];
   [touchOriginPoints setObject:touchOriginPointValue forKey:touch];
}
return [touchOriginPointValue CGPointValue];
```

---

If you must use the `CFDictionary` approach, you have to find a place to `free` those `malloc`-ed memory when the values are not needed. Therefore, you have to pass the values callbacks when creating the dictionary

```
static void free_malloced_memory (CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value) {
   free((void*)value);
}
static const CFDictionaryValueCallBacks values_callbacks = {0, NULL, free_malloced_memory, NULL, NULL};
...
touchOriginPoints = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, & values_callbacks);
...
```

Comment: Thanks KennyTM, I'll give those callback functions a shot.

Comment: CFDictionary is required because UITouch doesn't implement NSCopying. While implementing the callback function helps it doesn't eliminate all the related memory leaks.

Comment: @Shaun: Ah right. But since copying is the only issue, you still can use `CFDictionary` with `UITouch` as the keys, `NSValue` as the values, and use the `&kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks` value callbacks so that CF can track the ref-counting automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you must return the malloc'd value from the function, then you have passed the responsibility for freeing the memory to the calling function, or one of its callers.

Since we can't see the calling functions, we can't diagnose any more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be returning an object that is allocated, then either you need to have the caller `free()` it, or else you need to be using some kind of garbage collection (so it gets freed automatically).

Comment: 2 seconds behind my answer... :D

Comment: It's very sad that there is no GC in iPhoneOS. I realize that this is an iPhone specific comment, but my answer is a general-purpose one.

Answer (score 0):

you don't actually return a pointer, the value is copied to a temp value when it is returned, so you aren't really returning the allocation at all, the problem is that you just aren't freeing it either, you add the allocation to the dictionary and just leave it there?

is there like an EndOfTouch function? where you remove the touch from the dictionary? if there is, call free on your allocation there and you should be fine

Comment: There is a touchesEnded method where I free these allocations but I'm finding that when the touch delegate is removed mid-touch that method is never fired resulting in the orphaned allocations.

Comment: hmm, how is the touch delegate removed? (i'm not too familiar with iphone or objC for that matter). could you go through your list and free everything then?

aside from that, could you have a dictionary of actual objects, rather than a dictionary of pointers?, (i don't know how the CFDictionaryGetValue would return if it couldn't find the answer...)
that way there would be no allocations to free.