# Free malloc when its value is returned by a function

Tags: c, malloc

I have the following function:

```
char *lsl(){
    chdir("/Users/some/directory");
     FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = popen("ls -l", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("popen failed");
        return (char *)EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    size_t str_size = 1024;
    char *stringts = malloc(str_size);
    if (!stringts) {
        perror("stringts allocation failed");
        return (char *)EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    stringts[0] = '\0';

    char buf[128];
    size_t n;
    while ((n = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf) - 1, fp)) > 0) {
        buf[n] = '\0';
        size_t capacity = str_size - strlen(stringts) - 1;
        while (n > capacity) {
            str_size *= 2;
            stringts = realloc(stringts, str_size);
            if (!stringts) {
                perror("stringts realloation failed");
                return (char *)EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            capacity = str_size - strlen(stringts) - 1;
        }
        strcat(stringts, buf);
    }


    if (pclose(fp) != 0) {
       perror("pclose failed");
       return (char *)EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return stringts;
}
```

Related part in main:

```
 char *out=lsl();
    if(send(new_socket, out, 200, 0)<0){. //sending the string to the client to print it there
       printf("Error in send! %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1; 
    }
```

It returns a string to the main function, problem is I use `malloc()` to allocate memory for this function, if I use `free(stringts)` before `return` then obviously nothing will get returned, so how I my supposed to use `free()` while still returning it?

Note:

I found this link here: [How do I free() after malloc() when the result of malloc() is returned by the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145152/how-do-i-free-after-malloc-when-the-result-of-malloc-is-returned-by-the-fu)

It is not in the same programming language hence why I am asking again.

Comment: Obviously you cannot `free` a string that you want to return. Your function `lsl` allocates memory for a string, initializes and returns it. The function that calls `lsl` uses that string and calls `free` on it when it is done. (But that function is free to return the string to its caller in turn or to store the string somewhere else. Whoever receives the string "owns" it and is responsible to `free` it.)

Comment: `return (char *)EXIT_FAILURE;` No. Just return `NULL`. `strings = realloc(strings` if realloc fails, you leak memory. That's why you use a temporary pointer with realloc - `void *tmp = realloc(string); if (!tmp) { free(string); ... } string = tmp;`. `so how I my supposed to use free() while still returning it?` `free` it in `main` after use...

Comment: OT: using `strcat` is inefficient here. Google "Shlemiel the painter's algorithm" for more information.

Comment: How am I supposed to free it in `main()`? Since I need to send it to the client any thing after `send()` won't get executed while in the client I just read from a buffer I made.

Comment: @ayrebelcoding of course you can free it once you've sent it via `send`. Once it's sent, it's, well, sent. Same if you write something to a file, once it's written, it's in the file and you can free it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return it, you must not free() stringts.  You must later free() it in the calling function.

```
char *out=lsl();
int r = send(new_socket, out, 200, 0);
free(out);
    if(r <0){. //sending the string to the client to print it there
       printf("Error in send! %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1; 
    }
```